# NSDateFormatter doesRelativeDateFormatting returns unexpected relative day value

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdateformatter, macos-high-sierra

Using `NSDateFormatter` on macOS 10.13.3, I'm getting incorrect values when using `doesRelativeDateFormatting` set to `YES`. I've seen that there may be an issue with relative dates when using a custom format on the formatter but I am using standard `dateStyle` & `timeStyle` settings.

As an example, comparing the current date in New York City to the date in Sydney, Australia using appropriately configured date formatters without using `doesRelativeDateFormatting`, the string output from the date formatters correctly shows the day in Sydney being +1 from the day in NYC. When I enable `doesRelativeDateFormatting` on the same formatters, the relative date for Sydney returns incorrectly as same day ('Today'). Code that demonstrates these results:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *localDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        localDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
        localDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
        localDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;

        NSDateFormatter *remoteDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        remoteDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Sydney"];
        remoteDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
        remoteDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;

        NSLog(@"            Now in NYC: %@", [localDateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
        NSLog(@"         Now in Sydney: %@", [remoteDateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);

        localDateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
        remoteDateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

        NSLog(@"   Relative now in NYC: %@", [localDateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
        NSLog(@"Relative now in Sydney: %@", [remoteDateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2018-01-26 14:42:28.478 Untitled[40694:1821879]             Now in NYC: Friday, January 26, 2018 at 2:42:28 PM Eastern Standard Time
2018-01-26 14:42:28.479 Untitled[40694:1821879]          Now in Sydney: Saturday, January 27, 2018 at 6:42:28 AM Australian Eastern Daylight Time
2018-01-26 14:42:28.479 Untitled[40694:1821879]    Relative now in NYC: Today at 2:42:28 PM Eastern Standard Time
2018-01-26 14:42:28.479 Untitled[40694:1821879] Relative now in Sydney: Today at 6:42:28 AM Australian Eastern Daylight Time
```

Is this a bug in `NSDateFormatter` or am I doing something wrong in my configuration of the formatter? Thanks.

Comment: You really should post your "update" as a new question focused on what you are trying to achieve with relative formatting so it gets fresh attention. Then rollback the changes you made to this one.

Comment: The way I understand it is that if there is new information, you're to update the original post (as the placeholder for this very comment suggests). This post now has enough information to be helpful to others, I think, and it's put me on the right path to get the result I want. Certainly I'm a novice in comparison to you when it comes to SO but it just doesn't seem necessary to post a new question. If you are emphatic about this, I'll do it but I don't fully see the benefit. Thanks again or your help.

Comment: Seconding rmaddy's point. Yes, updating your question is fine, but it doesn't make sense to accept his answer and then add a whole other query to your post. (It's also a bit unkind to change the question after someone answers, don't you think?) Please do repost the new section separately; since it's working and you want suggestions, you might also consider posting it on [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: I guess the issue for me is that I didn't see the final line as a new query. I'm not actively seeking further assistance on this issue — it was adequately  resolved using rmaddy's answer as demonstrated by the updated code. I'm happy to remove the final line about being open to suggestions and just be done with this. Truly not trying to be obstinate here but still failing to see the benefit of posting another question for something that has been, for all intents and purposes, resolved.

Comment: As to changing the title of the question, the question itself, as demonstrated by rmaddy's answer was flawed, the results weren't incorrect just not what I was expecting and to remove aspersions from others, the updated title reflected that the error resided in my misunderstanding. Not sure how that's unkind, I think it better reflects the nature of the issue and will be more helpful to others should they also fine themselves getting unexpected results.

Comment: Since you consider it resolved, maybe the new code makes more sense as an answer. [It's fine to post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I've done as you've suggested but, ultimately, this doesn't feel correct to me. The code in the initial query is wrong and the accepted answer doesn't have the updated code so it's possible people coming to this thread later won't scroll all the way down to see the updated working code. But, alas, I'm deferring to you both as having a greater understanding of this resource than I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output is correct. Call anyone on the phone anywhere in the world and ask them what the date is and they will all say "today". Just because it's a different day of the week in two parts of the world doesn't mean it isn't "today" locally everywhere.

You are letting yourself get confused by comparing the output of two different timezones that happen to be in two different days when the code is run.

The idea of "relative" date formatting is that the output is a string relative to "now" in the given timezone. It's not relative to any other timezone. Whichever one is set on the date formatter.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) is correct. Enabling `doesRelativeDateFormatting` and then comparing the date to its own timezone will report 'Today', as it should.

So, the key is to get the date in the remote timezone then use that date relative to the preferred (local) timezone and using the local date formatter's relative date string. Modifying my code to account for the time difference between the two timezones, I calculate the local date offset by the delta and use the local date formatter to get the date string (still using the remote date formatter for the time string because it includes the timezone name).

This isn't perfect because I'm not properly localizing the string (' at ' is being manually inserted without localization) but this modified code basically gets the results for which I'm looking:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

        NSDateFormatter *localDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        localDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
        localDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
        localDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;

        NSDateFormatter *remoteDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        remoteDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Sydney"];
        remoteDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
        remoteDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;

        NSLog(@"            Now in NYC: %@", [localDateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
        NSLog(@"         Now in Sydney: %@", [remoteDateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);

        localDateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

        NSLog(@"   Relative now in NYC: %@", [localDateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);

        NSInteger localSecondsFromGMT = [localDateFormatter.timeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:now];
        NSInteger remoteSecondsFromGMT = [remoteDateFormatter.timeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:now];
        NSInteger remoteTimeZoneDelta = (remoteSecondsFromGMT - localSecondsFromGMT);
        NSDate *remoteDate = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)remoteTimeZoneDelta];
        localDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
        remoteDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
        NSString *remoteRelativeDate = [localDateFormatter stringFromDate:remoteDate];
        NSString *remoteRelativeTime = [remoteDateFormatter stringFromDate:now];

        NSLog(@"Relative now in Sydney: %@ at %@", remoteRelativeDate, remoteRelativeTime);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2018-01-27 16:08:12.856 Untitled[95771:3146343]             Now in NYC: Saturday, January 27, 2018 at 4:08:12 PM Eastern Standard Time
2018-01-27 16:08:12.857 Untitled[95771:3146343]          Now in Sydney: Sunday, January 28, 2018 at 8:08:12 AM Australian Eastern Daylight Time
2018-01-27 16:08:12.857 Untitled[95771:3146343]    Relative now in NYC: Today at 4:08:12 PM Eastern Standard Time
2018-01-27 16:08:12.857 Untitled[95771:3146343] Relative now in Sydney: Tomorrow at 8:08:12 AM Australian Eastern Daylight Time
```

This is somewhat inelegant but it works for my current needs.